# What could have caused my Chrome and Google account to revert to it's original state a year ago?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, google-accounts

About a year ago, in August 2013, I came home from work to find that my home copy of Chrome turned sour. I had tabs open which I didn't when I left home, my bookmarks were changed to my original ones from 2009, my default search engine was changed to one of those really dodgy ones. My computer was on during the day, but the only person who was in the house was the cleaning lady, who I doubt knows enough about computers to have caused it.

So after the initial shock, I managed to import a recent export of my bookmarks, activated 2 factor authentication, clean all apparent traces of whatever was happened, and checked my Google Dashboard for my account activity. The weird thing is that my Google Account Activity didn't show any suspicious logins from other places. And even if my maid (or someone who she let in) accessed my computer, A) how could she have reverted my bookmarks to a 4 year old status and B) what use would she have had for it?

I'm thinking that it was probably something that went wrong at Google's side, but I still don't understand what could have caused it. How could this have happened?

Comment: maybe best to contact google support for issues like this? they like to hear about glitches so they can investigate and prevent them in the future and for other users. they also have a better view on what exactly happened.

Comment: Yeah, that was also one of the first things I did. I made a question on their support forums, but I had not a single response to that.

Comment: Instead of using the forums (which are largely user based), try contacting them. You can choose for them to call you, chat, email, ... there are lots of ways to get their attention.